# Figma: "text align justified" not working

Tags: text-alignment, figma

does anyone know how to justify text in Figma to have the width of the entire textblock?
The option is not working somehow:
[image: figma not justifying text]

Thanks, Richy

### Answered by Ivan in the comments!

Comment: Just to check. Are you sure you didn't press "Enter" after "hello world"?